# Java Swing Panel will not update the display of a label

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I've got three classes, an initiator class, a calculations class, and a Swing GUI class.

In the GUI I have a button that submits the selections to a method of the calculator class (not a main class). I have verified that the method works, and does indeed change the label on the GUI class (via *System.out.println(guiTravel.trip_Miles.getText());*) . However the Swing panel does not reflect the changes.

I've tried adding in redraw(), revalidate(), repaint(), and updateUI(), all from within the calculations method. None of it seems to reflect the change.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated? I'm relatively new to using swing (and java more or 
less).

This is the code for the button to launch the method:

```
private void Next_TripActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    sauCalc.calculateDistance();
}
```

This is the method in the calculate class:

```
package sau_travel_log;

public class SAU_Calculator {
   double[] BVS  = new double[] { 0.0, 10.0, 18.0,  8.0,  4.2,  4.6, 17.0};
   double[] HCMS = new double[] {10.0,  0.0,  9.6,  2.0,  5.8,  6.2, 15.0};
   double[] PVS  = new double[] {17.8,  9.6,  0.0,  9.8, 13.6, 14.0, 13.0};
   double[] SAU  = new double[] { 8.0,  2.0,  9.8,  0.0,  3.8,  4.2, 17.0};
   double[] WES  = new double[] { 4.2,  5.8, 13.6,  3.8,  0.0,  0.4, 20.8};
   double[] WHS  = new double[] { 4.6,  6.2, 14.0,  4.2,  0.4,  0.0, 21.2};
   double[] WVS  = new double[] {25.0, 15.0, 13.0, 17.0, 20.8, 21.2,  0.0};

   double[][] distanceTraveled = {BVS, HCMS, PVS, SAU, WES, WHS, WVS};
   int selectionOne;
   int selectionTwo;

   boolean endDayLoop = false;
   boolean endMonthLoop = false;

   double travelOfDay = 0.0;
   double travelOfMonth = 0.0;   

   public SAU_Travel_Log_GUI guiTravel;

   public void testClass(SAU_Travel_Log_GUI guiTravel) {
       this.guiTravel = guiTravel;
   }

   public void calculateDistance() {
       double tripMileage = distanceTraveled[selectionOne][selectionTwo];
       travelOfDay += tripMileage;

       guiTravel.trip_Miles.setText(String.valueOf(tripMileage));
       guiTravel.day_Miles.setText(String.valueOf(travelOfDay));
       guiTravel.month_Miles.setText(String.valueOf(travelOfMonth));


       guiTravel.trip_Miles.repaint();
   }
}
```

I have updated the calculator class to reflect my changes from Hovercraft's suggestion. However now I get the following:

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Any ideas?

Comment: You've got problems, a bug, in code not shown. Perhaps you unknowingly have more than one instance of a class.... but who knows. If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: I bet that missing code needs something like label.setText(newString) instead of redraws and all that other junk.

Comment: @MarsAtomic: You're quite possibly right. Myself, I'm terrible at reading minds or guessing at code I can't see.

Answer (score 1):

Amazingly, your problem is exactly as I've guessed in my first comment (dang, I'm lucky today) -- you unknowingly have more than one instance of a class and then setting its text:

```
public void calculateDistance() {
    SAU_Travel_Log_GUI guiTravel = new SAU_Travel_Log_GUI();  // ****** here ***
```

This means that any changes to the state of this SAU_Travel_Log_GUI will occur in a SAU_Travel_Log_GUI object that is not visible, since this new instance is completely distinct from the visualized SAU_Travel_Log_GUI instance.

The solution to the problem: don't do this. Set the text of the labels on the actual visualized GUI. To do this, you can pass the actual visualized instance in this class's constructor (or setter method if you desire):

```
public SomeClass {
  private SAU_Travel_Log_GUI guiTravel;

  public SomeClass(SAU_Travel_Log_GUI guiTravel) {
     this.guiTravel = guiTravel;

     // ... plus other methods
  }

    public void calculateDistance() {

        // **** no need for this now
        // ****  SAU_Travel_Log_GUI guiTravel = new SAU_Travel_Log_GUI();

        double tripMileage = distanceTraveled[selectionOne][selectionTwo];
        travelOfDay += tripMileage;


        // *** now you're setting text on actual components of the visualized GUI
        guiTravel.trip_Miles.setText(String.valueOf(tripMileage));
        guiTravel.day_Miles.setText(String.valueOf(travelOfDay));
        guiTravel.month_Miles.setText(String.valueOf(travelOfMonth));

                                                              VALUE WHEN RAN
        guiTravel.trip_Miles.repaint();
    }
```

Then when you call the constructor for this class, pass in a reference to the actual visualized SAU_Travel_Log_GUI instance.

Note: better to use public methods to allow outside classes to set text on private fields of the class.